# private typedef visible in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef

I have a small problem with my compiler (VC++ 6.0). In my opinion, such a code should cause error;

```
class Base
{
    private:
        typedef int T;
};

class Derived : private Base // Here the Base class can be inherited publicly as well. It does not play any role
{
    public:
        T z;
};



int main()
{
    Derived obj;
    obj.z = 7;
    return 0;
}
```

This code snippet is compiled and run under VC++ 6.0 without any problem.

Regarding SW-Design, this code is not perfect. None of the class member members should be declared as public. But I am not interested in this aspect.

My problem is with typedef. The typedef is declared in Base class as private. From my point of C++ understanding, this typedef must not be visible either to Derived class or to main() function. But both see them perfectly.

Does anybody have an explanation to this phenomenon?

Thanks in advance

Necip

Comment: I tried to compile it with VS 2008 - can not access private typedef declared in class Base. It is interesting why it is ok in VS 6

Comment: VC6 has many issues of non conformance with the standard.

Comment: @Svetlozar, VC++ 6.0 is old, even predates the standard publication IIRC.  As usual, non conformance reasons ranges from anachronisms -- the language have changed -- to bugs passing by extensions and the result of different resolutions than the standard blessed one for issues.

Comment: Nevertheless, that is not my decision to work with VC++ 6.0. It is unfortunately standard tool in our company and in spite of its non-conformances, I have to program on it. –

Comment: I would seek to change company if i were forced to work with *that* an old compiler, frankly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is a non conformance in VC++6.0, you should have got an error when defining Derived::z.  (Excepted if you have business reasons to use it, there are other choices technically preferable to VC++6.0 which is *old*).